# How do I stop objects from being displayed as cursive in fira code iScript?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to switch to fira code iScript so I can get the keywords to be in cusrsive, var, const, class delete import, private, public ect... however it is making all objects cursive as well even though it is defined in the config not to do this, I've moved everything in to the exclude section and it continues to make objects cursive:

```
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": [
                //following will be in italic (=FlottFlott)
            ],
            "settings": {
                "fontStyle": "italic"
            }
        },
        {
            "scope": [
                //following will be excluded from italics (VSCode has some defaults for italics)
                "invalid",
                "storage.modifier", //static keyword
                "storage.type.class.js", //class keyword
                "entity.name.type.class", //class names
                "keyword.operator",
                "constant.numeric.css",
                "keyword.other.unit.px.css",
                "constant.numeric.decimal.js",
                "constant.numeric.json",
                "comment",
                "keyword", //import, export, return…
                "constant", //String, Number, Boolean…, this, super
                "entity.name.type.class", //class names
                "entity.other.attribute-name",
                "entity.name.method",
                "entity.name.tag",
                "variable.language",
                "meta.paragraph.markdown",
                "support.type.property-name.json",
                "string.other.link.title.markdown"
            ],
            "settings": {
                "fontStyle": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

produces this output:
the section in orange should not be in cursive. (italic)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

after further research the answer is:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": [
                //following will be in italic (=FlottFlott)
                "keyword", //import, export, return…
                "constant" //String, Number, Boolean…, this, super
            ],
            "settings": {
                "fontStyle": "italic"
            }
        },
        {
            "scope": [
                //following will be excluded from italics (VSCode has some defaults for italics)
                "invalid",
                "storage.modifier", //static keyword
                "storage.type.class.js", //class keyword
                "entity.name.type.class", //class names
                "keyword.operator",
                "constant.numeric.css",
                "keyword.other.unit.px.css",
                "constant.numeric.decimal.js",
                "constant.numeric.json",
                "comment",
                "entity.name.type.class", //class names
                "entity.other.attribute-name",
                "entity.name.method",
                "entity.name.tag",
                "variable.language",
                "meta.paragraph.markdown",
                "support.type.property-name.json",
                "string.other.link.title.markdown",
                "variable.other.object.property",
                "object",
                "variable.language.this",
                "variable.other.object"
            ],
            "settings": {
                "fontStyle": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```